# Centering continuous variables in a multilevel logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

We are fitting a two-level logistic regression model with continuous variables in Level 1 and no variables in Level 2, except the groups.

We considered only a random intercept in the model, but it is possible to consider a random slope for one or more independent variables.

What is the best method to center the variables in Level 1, by the total mean or by the group means?

Comment: Not sure if this is new to you or not, but this paper is great on the topic https://osf.io/mt5z3/download

Comment: There is quite a large literacture on this. What is the purpose of your model ? What is/are your research question/s ?

Comment: Please can you provide more details about this ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not answered the questions in the comments and has not been on the site in years.